# How can I scan a every tile in a game in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

So I am trying to scan for every tile in a game ("scan" as stepping in a tile and saving its coordinates). If the player bumps against an object, then it must try to go to one tile down and keep walking. I can even know which face the player is facing.

I am using `pydirectinput` because `pyautogui` wasn't really working with my game.

This is my code so far:

```
def coordinates():
    visited_coordinates = []
    t_end = time.time() + 90
    movements = []
    while time.time() < t_end:
        for message in generated_object():  # generated object returns a list with 4 elements
            if [message[0], message[1]] in visited_coordinates:
                if "left" in movements:
                    if "down" in movements:
                        if "right" in movements:
                            pydirectinput.press("up")
                            if message[3] != 4:  # 4 means it is facing up
                                pydirectinput.press("up")  # if it isn't facing up, it needs to be pressed twice
                            movements.append("up")
                        else:
                            pydirectinput.press("right")
                            if message[3] != 12:  # 12 means it is facing right
                                pydirectinput.press("right")  # same with facing right, and so on
                            movements.append("right")
                    else:
                        pydirectinput.press("down")
                        if message[3] != 0:  # 0 means it is facing down
                            pydirectinput.press("down")
                        movements.append("down")
                else:
                    pydirectinput.press("left")
                    if message[3] != 8:  # 8 means it is facing left
                        pydirectinput.press("left")
                    movements.append("left")
                continue
            movements = []
            if message[2] != 4:  # this means it went beyond the border, and it must return
                pydirectinput.press("right", presses=2)
            visited_coordinates.append([message[0], message[1]])

    return visited_coordinates
```

One (of the many) problems with this code is that it takes forever to perform an action (I am working with named pipes, so I have to read every received message). And in the same vein, this is classic spaghetti code, which we all despise.

How can I write this code to be more "readable" and more efficient?

And on the other hand, as soon as I go beyond that border, I can't really come back. I should make the player not to move left again, but I don't really know how since I've been resetting the `movements` list

Answer (score 0):

Could put items in a dictionary, then loop through those entries.

```
directions = { 'up': 4, 'right': 12, 'down': 0, 'left':8 }

for direction, val in directions .items():
    if direction in movements:
        pydirectinput .press( direction )
        if message[3] != val:
            pydirectinput .press( direction )
        movements .append( direction )
        break  ##  you might want to break out of the loop here
```